# Getting "resource_already_exists_exception" when trying to update stopwords

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch version 6.8

I have an exsisting index (name q1) and I want to update it's stop words list.

I tried to do it with the following command:

```
PUT /q1
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "my_stop": {
                    "type":       "stop",
                    "stopwords": ["daa", "dada", "the"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I got errors:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
                "reason": "index [q1/lywbfw9QTaeYVr0dpDnRvw] already exists",
                "index_uuid": "lywbfw9QTaeYVr0dpDnRvw",
                "index": "q1"
            }
        ],
        "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
        "reason": "index [q1/lywbfw9QTaeYVr0dpDnRvw] already exists",
        "index_uuid": "lywbfw9QTaeYVr0dpDnRvw",
        "index": "q1"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

seems that I can set the stop words (with this command) just for a new index and not for exsisting one.

What is wrong, and how can I update the stop words list of my q1 index ?

Thanks

Comment: were you able to find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

you need to close your index for updating and open it after.
See more about closing https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-close.html
and opening index https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-open-close.html

```
https://hostname:9200/your_index_name/_close
```

after

```
    PUT /your_index_name/_settings
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "my_stop": {
                    "type":       "stop",
                    "stopwords": ["daa", "dada", "the"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
https://hostname:9200/your_index_name/_open
```

Comment: Unlike doc that indicates to use PUT /my_index { "settings": {} }, this answer is the correct way to do so. So don't forget to use /_settings otherwise, you'll have an error like, resource already exists